# Using a web framework as python GUI

Tags: python, gui, django

If I built some useful piece of python code to e.g. scrape a website or to calculate something big, at some point I might want to add a GUI to my project. For this I could use Tk, Qt, Pygame or any python graphic/GUI framework.

Now I also want this tool to be usable by clients without the need for a python installation. Of course I could use something like py2Exe or py2Dmg. But wouldn't it be cooler to use a python-based web framework for this? Something like Django or Pyramid.

What would be the drawbacks of doing this? Can I just use the framework to execute my code on a server and only return the result? Or will this get tricky when there are multiple users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a web UI will make it easier to extend, and update. But it will be another layer of complexity for you to deal with.

I recommend looking at the lightweight http://webpy.org/

```
    urls = (
        '/hello', 'hello'
    )
    app = web.application(urls, globals())

    class hello:        
        def POST(self, name):
            #call your script here
```

You can call this with POST localhost/hello

Benefits:

- Portability: no installers, can access from anywhere.
- Extensibility: easyer to modify the UI (if you know HTML/CSS) and easier to re-deploy your application.

drawbacks:

- Complexity: you will need to understand HTML, CSS request/response etc, set up a webserver or shared hosting,
- Security: don't make it public.

Comment: Thanks! I already have experience with Django so the complexity won't be to much of a problem. What's with security? Why would this construction be extra vulnerable?

Comment: if you make your web server accessible to the internet, people may try and attack it. There are all kinds of attacks to watch out for, it's probably best/easiest to set up a firewall to allow internal network access only    https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Answer (score 0):

If you use Django, I recommend looking at either of

- [django-tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). With it you can build simple REST-style interfaces to your code.
- [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). An asynchronous task framework

Since you mention `calculating something big`you are likely to need asynchronous processing. Celery is a great choice for that. It includes the ability to submit jobs via REST calls, and to check on their status.